# MongoDB equivalent for LOWER() in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, mongodb, database-migration

I have a PostgreSQL query, which looks like `LOWER(content) LIKE '%lra%'`. I am migrating this to MonogoDB. I am looking for an equivalent. This is what I have so far

```
db.contents.find({content: /lra/i})
```

I am doing it by means of regular expression. Is there a way to specify it something like this:

```
db.contents.find({content: {$lower: /lra/}})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not without a full table scan at the moment.

The best way is to store the string in another field already in lower case and then store a "real" field with it untouched.

You could do this with the aggregation framework using http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/toLower/#exp._S_toLower but that wouldn't be all that much better than the regex you show above frankly.

As @AdaTheDev found, there is a JIRA for it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90

Comment: Just to add, this jira item is worth watching: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90